# How to partition 2D-points into intervals (using only vertical lines)?

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, data-science, k-means

So I have a 2D scatter filled with points `(x,y)`. I want to draw k vertical lines `(x_1 = a, x_2 = b, ..., x_k = k)`, so as to partition the points into k groups.

The optimal solution would minimize the average variance of each group's `y_value`.

What is the appropriate algorithm? It sounded like k-means but I have the constraint that the lines must be vertical.

Comment: I'm not sure clustering algorithms would be of any help here, because you have too many constraints. Did you think about a dynamic programming approach (your solution is a set of k distinct integers of `[1,n]` representing the indices of the `x_i` where a line cuts) ? It 'smells' a lot like DP to me.

Comment: Can you please formalise what you're seeking to minimise? (How are the variance and average variance calculated and what, mathematically, are we minimising)

Comment: I want to minimize the sum of the y-distances of each point to the group's average y_value.
So it would be:
 min{ sum_over-all-groups[sum_over-all-points-of-group[ (y - average_y_of_group)^2 ] ]  }

subject to : 
the maximum x-value of group_1 is lower than the minimum x_value of group2
the maximum x-value of group_2 is lower than the minimum x_value of group3
etc.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an idea based on dynamic programming.
With the following notations:
`(x_1, y_1), ..., (x_n, y_n)` the points, with `x_1 <= x_2 <= ... <= x_n` to cut in `K` groups.
`Var(i, j)` the variance of the `y`'s: `y_i, ..., y_j`.
`F_K((x_1,y_1), ..., (x_n, y_n)) = F_k(1,n)` the value of the best solution for the problem.

Then we have the following:
`F_k(i,j) = min for l in i...j-k+1 of (Var(i,l) + F_(k-1)(l+1, j)` and
`F_1(i,j) = Var(i,j)`.

The property above simply means that the best way to split your points in 'k' groups is to select the leftmost cut (the choice of `l`), and the best choice of `k-1` cuts for the remaining points.

From there you can go for a dynamic program. You'll need a 3D array `A` of dimensions `n*n*K` to store the value of F_k(i,j) for all `i,j,k`. 
The program would look like:

```
function get_value(P: points, A: 3D array, i, j, k){
  if A[i][j][k] is defined{
    result = A[i][j][k]
  } else if k == 1 {
    A[i][j][k] = get_var(P, i, j)
    result = A[i][j][k] 
  } else {
    result = +INF
    for l in i ... j-k+1 {
      tmp = get_value(P, A, i, l, 1) + get_value(P, A, l+1, j, k-1)
      if tmp < result {
        result = tmp
      }
    }
  }
  return result
}
```

NB: I was a bit quick about the range to iterate on for `l`, that might be something to look into.